# Is it possible to send text files as request message to Google PubSub

Tags: google-app-engine, publish-subscribe

I am trying to store files from on Google Storage. However, I do not want my primary GAE to spend time behind it. Hence I am pushing this task onto Google PubSub which further pushes it to another GAE. I know that its possible to send encoded string via Google PubSub. Is it possible to achieve the same for text files ?

Comment: If your file consists of bytes then sure it's possible

Comment: Yep. file contains comma separated values. So, do I read the file, make list and publish that list through PubSub ? Or are you talking about publishing `file.txt` to PubSub ?

Comment: I mean PubsubMessage takes `byte[]`. If you know how to get bytes, you can achieve this